# With Gravity Forms Product Add-ons + Woocommerce, is possible to create an add to cart link?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Here's the scenario:

I have a product using gravity forms product add-ons with prepopulated fields in the URL.

Example: website.com/product/book/?title=BookTitle&price=9.99
When a user clicks the link, the fields are prepopulated into the product so when the user clicks the add to cart button on the product page, the details are injected into the product and displayed on the cart & checkout pages. This part works well.

Is it possible to create an add-to-cart link that includes the URL parameters?

Example: website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=20762&title=BookTitle&price=9.99
I know this probably doesn't work like this, but ideally, I want a simple add to cart button that adds the product to the cart and also includes the URL parameter information.